# Slice a list with for loop range function in Django templates

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I am developing a Django application about statistics calculations. But now I have faced a problem that I can't solve. I have two lists in my views.py `list1 = [5, 6, 7, 8]` `list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]`. I sent this to Django templates and I also sent `'n' : range(7)` as context.

In my html code, there have a code

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>list1</th>
            <th>list2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Now I want to print first value of each list in first row, then second value of each list in second row and so on.

So I have made a code something like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>list1</th>
            <th>list2</th>
        </tr>
        {% for i in n %}
        <tr>
            <td> {{ list1.i }} </td>
            <td>{{ list2.i }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </thead>
</table>
```

After writting this code, I am not getting any error but the values are not showing. Instead a blank row and columns are being made.

Please help me to print the values that I want to print.

Comment: You can't use range(n) in the template.  You can't access elements of list by index like normally it is done in python. You have to zip it like the below answer.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you should keep all the logic on views.
What I'd do is zip the lists and use tuples instead.

views.py:

```
new_list = zip(list1, list2)
context = {
            'new_list': mylist,
        }
```

and on templates:

```
{% for list1_item, list2_item in new_list %}
    <tr>
            <td> {{ list1_item }} </td>
            <td> {{ list2_item }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```